# Managing Contact count in Salesforce Marketing Cloud

Tags: marketing-cloud, marketing-cloud-connect

We are using Marketing Cloud Connect to integrate SFMC with SF CRM. Currently, we are syncing the Lead, User, Contact object. If I delete a Lead record from SF CRM, it gets reflected in the Synced Lead Object in SFMC. However, it does not get deleted in All Contacts.

Is there a way to identify the record in All contact which has been deleted from Salesforce CRM?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar situation where I had to delete duplicate records and SFDC records that didn’t have an email address that were synchronized from Marketing Cloud Connect.

Here’s what I did:
Import the deleted Leads from SFDC into a SFMC data extension, then from Contact Builder in the All Contacts tab, click on the trash can icon in the top right of the page and choose “Delete contacts from data extension”. Select your data extension you created then click the delete contacts button.

It’s not an ideal process but it’s the only way I know of to delete bulk records from All Contacts since there’s no way to query this table via SQL in the UI.

Hope this helps!